# If I see a blocked remote port number, who's firewall is to blame?

Tags: sockets, port, ip-address, firewall

I no longer have the ability to receive messages from a port at a remote ip address. I can currently ping the remote ip address with no problem. I have a python program that tries to create a socket that connects to that remote port/ip address, but it indicates that the port is closed.

I assume this is a firewall issue. Is this a correct assumption? Who's firewall is to blame, mine or the one at the remote location?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assume this is a firewall issue. Is this a correct assumption?

Not necessarily. It might be that there is simply no  service running at the IP and port you are trying to reach.

> Who's firewall is to blame, mine or the one at the remote location?

If a firewall is too blame at all it might be at anywhere between the client and the server, i.e. at the client, at the server or at some router or other middlebox in between.